# IIS/web.config URL Rewrite remove subfolder from url

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Let's say I have a domain called mydomain.com. And I added a subfolder call site1 for example and I also registered a subdomain with the same name. Which means I want to map **site1.mydomain.com** to **site1.mydomain.com/site1** but I dont want to **/site1** to show up.

This is the first time I do that, I just read the following article, it was pretty handy but it still doesnt work for url. Anchors are getting rewritten correctly but the url doesnt work.
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/05/26/url-rewrite-multiple-domains-under-one-site-part-ii.aspx

Here is what I have

```
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
                <rewrite>
                        <rules>
                                <rule name="in a subfolder" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                                        <match url=".*" />
                                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                                                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?site1.mydomain\.com$" />
                                                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/site1($|/)" negate="true" />
                                        </conditions>
                                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/site1/{R:0}" />
                                </rule>
                        </rules>
                        <outboundRules>
                                <rule name="Outgoing - URL paths" enabled="true">
                                        <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^(?:site1|(.*//[_a-zA-Z0-9-\.]*)?/site1)(.*)" />
                                        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}" />
                                </rule>
                                <rule name="response_location URL">
                                        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^(?:site1.mydomain.com|(.*//[_a-zA-Z0-9-\.]*)?/site1)(.*)" />
                                        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}" />
                                </rule>
                                <rule name="response_location querystring">
                                        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="(.*)%2fsite1(.*)" />
                                        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}" />
                                </rule>
                        </outboundRules>
                </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There is probably an obvious error in regex or something, but I am not understanding every single part of this config so it might be why. If you cant give an answer maybe you can explain me more what this does?

Thank you,

Comment: Hi Burnzy. I don't have an answer for you, but I'm in the same boat with trying to remove that first subfolder from the URL of my subdomains. Have you been able to resolve this problem? If so would you mind posting the rules in their entirety as an answer to your question here? Thanks.

Comment: @rwkiii I actually was able to figure it out, and got it working. Unfortunately I lost the code. I'll try to work it out for you later today, only thing I remember is that this code was really close to the solution and article I posted was the only resource I used.

Comment: @rwkiii Out of curiosity just replace **<action type="Rewrite" url="/site1/{R:0}" />** to **<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}" />**